# joint pdf of $X$ and $Y$ find constant

Tags: probability, statistics

$$f(x, y) = ce^{−x−y}$$ for $0 \le x \le y < \infty$,

Calculate the value for $c$ that makes $f$ a valid pdf.

how do you find $c$ when the domain of $x$ and $y$ both contain each other?

Answer (score 2):

Note that $f$ takes value $0$ in points $\langle x,y\rangle$ where $0\leq x\leq y<\infty$ is not satisfied.

Based on the following equality (characteristic for PDF) you can find $c$:$$1=\int\int f(x,y)dxdy=\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^yce^{-x-y}dxdy$$

Comment: Alternatively$\displaystyle 1= \int\int f(x,y)\,dy\,dx=\int_{x=0}^{\infty}\int_{y=x}^{\infty} ce^{-x-y}\,dy\,dx$